# The drawing is not as significant as needed

Tags: sculpting

I'm watching Blender Sculpting introduction [here](https://youtu.be/TAGWu08oWAM?t=137). Here's the screenshot. As you can see, the drawing on path is very significant and easily can be seen:

[image]

But in my case, it's very smooth and not as significant. It's true for all those brushes available. I tried maximum strength but still not getting the look shown in tutorial.

[image]

The tutorial guy recommended a pen for sculpting. I use Mouse instead. Could that be a reason?

Comment: do you have as many faces?

Comment: @moonboots means? I'm new I don't know much.

Comment: does your object have as many polygons as the object in the video?

Comment: @moonboots  the guy didn't tell anything about the sphere settings. It was already there. So I can't know how many faces.

Comment: maybe you don't have enough polygons but we can't tell, maybe show your wireframe, or go in Edit mode, select all and right click > Subdivide to have more polygons? If it still doesn't fix your problem, please share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: @moonboots I added Subdivision Surface using Modifiers (4) but still the drawing is not as sharp as in the tutorial. Here's open file https://pasteall.org/blend/d3b2d58d43094a44ae684efc1410b22a

Comment: If you watch the tutorial attentively, you can see at [1:34](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TAGWu08oWAM&t=94s) when he's switching to _Edit Mode_ that he has a highly subdivided geometry. The _Subdivision Surface_ modifier you are using only creates more **real** geometry when you apply it. I also think he doesn't use a _UV Sphere_ but actually a _Cube_ rounded by _Subdivision Surface_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have enough topology to have a thin sculpt, you've given a *Subdivision Surface* modifier to your sphere but it only creates virtual topology to improve the appearance of your object, it can't make the sculpt thinner because sculpting only change the real topology. You need to subdivide your object in *Edit* mode (in that case make sure to have a *Smooth* value of 1 in the *Operator* box, otherwise it will flatten your faces), or apply the modifier (but 4 levels may be a bit too much though). You can also use the *Dyntopo* option. The *Multiresolution* modifier works differently than the *Subdivsion Surface* modifier and can save your sculpt.

Comment: Applying the Modifier = Dividing?

Comment: if you apply the Subdivision Surface it will subdivide the topology for real, choose a level of 3 for example, if it's not enough for your needs, try 4

Comment: for now I've deleted the modifier and subdivided like you said using Edit mode. It solved the problem, but my sphere is not as smooth as it was before. I mean weird look, please see this: https://imgur.com/gtBF2k0

Comment: the other technics to give more topology would be Dyntopo or Multiresolution modifier (which is also virtual topology but it will take sculpt into account), maybe just begin with a simple subdivision, either with the Subdivision Surface modifier, or right click > Subdivide (keep the subdivision smooth with the Smooth value at 1 in the Operator box)

Comment: I'll read about Sudivision Surface and Subdivide difference later. I think they are different things.

Comment: Yes because when you right click > subdivide you need to put the Smooth value at 1 in the Operator box, otherwise the additional edge loops will tend to flatten the existing faces

Comment: No the result is the same except the modifier will smooth by default, not right click > Subdivide, you need to choose a Smooth value of 1

Comment: thank you! it fixed the problem. I was applying subdivide multiple times, instead of changing the settings of 1st one.

Comment: @moonboots A level of 4 is quite high, but in the video it looks like he had a cube and used a Subsurf of level 6 or even 7.

Comment: Also, I still don't understand why the subsurface didn't give me same effect? I mean sphere was smooth, but drawing wasn't as significant as in case of subdivide.

Comment: oh ok, well it depends on his needs, I meant to get the result he shows in the screenshot he doesn't need 4 or more, 3 seems enough but if he needs a high amount of detail and if his computer is powerful enough, he can choose more

Comment: I'm just learning it not making actual project :P

Comment: @Vikas, because with the Subsurf modifier you only add virtual topology and when you sculpt you don't change this virtual topology, only the real one, which is low poly for the moment. The Multiresolution modifier works differently but maybe subdivide for real instead, either with right click or applying the modifier

Comment: @moonboots i found the culprit in subdivision surface :P you have to *apply* it right? :D now i'm seeing same effect as in case of subdivide.

Comment: mmh if you apply the modifier it works fine, not sure what you mean

Comment: @moonboots yeah I meant same. thanks

Comment: i'll be back with more questions